# wp-admin redirects to subdirectory after moving installation to subdirectory

Tags: login, directory

I have moved a wordpress installation to a subdirectory, from `var/www/html` to `var/www/html/wp-blog` mainly to make it future proof. I have followed the instructions in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). My server is configured as such

1. I have a nginx reverse proxy which directs calls to `blog.mysite.com` to the port 8080.
2. Apache listens on 8080
3. I have modified the `.htaccess` from what is given in the codex and it is as follows

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-blog/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp-blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I have only changed the `^(www.)?` test to `blog` since I don't want `www`. Also although the wordpress instance is in a subfolder I would like to server it via `blog.mysite.com` and the admin at `blog.mysite.com/wp-admin`.

Now my trouble is that when I use the the url `blog.mysite.com/wp-admin` it takes me a the login page but I get stuck in a loop after that. I noticed that my url in the address bar has a `redirect_to` set at `blog.mysite.com/wp-blog/wp-admin`. If I remove `wp-blog` from the redirect url, I am able to login.

The weird part is that, if the session gets over while I am in the admin page, the redirect url is fine!

At this point I have changed the `Wordpress URL` in the General Settings to `blog.mysite.com/wp-blog` and everything works as far as I see. But as I said before I would like to use the admin panel on the root.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the two URLs in the wp-options table of your database. One is for the 'regular' URL, and one is used to build the 'admin' URL.

Both should be just your domain, as in https://www.example.com .

Comment: I have verified it. Even when both the urls are my site urls only, the redirect contains the folder name